# How to Get php code from other server and implement to current page

Tags: php, html

I have txt file on server 1, on that txt file i write php and html code like this :

```
<b>I want to eat <?=$keyword;?></b>
```

Then on server 2, I want to pull that data and implement to current page on server 2. I try to use this code :

```html
<?
$keyword = 'pizza';
$data = file_get_contents( 'http://www.domain.com/text.txt');
echo $data;
;?>
```

I want the result on server 2 page will display 'I want to eat pizza' but it just written "I want to eat".

It possible ?

Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get PHP to replace the variable with the value of said variable on a string in a text file, which isn't going to work. You could use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) (extremely hacky solution) or you could change the string on server 1 to something like `<b>I want to eat %food%</b>` and then use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace %food% with your keyword on server 2 by doing `echo str_replace("%food%", $keyword, file_get_contents('http://www.domain.com/text.txt'));`

Comment: Thank you very much. eval function working fine on my code now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this on the server 2:

```
<?php
$keyword = 'pizza';
include('http://www.domain.com/text.txt');
?>
```

And this on the server 1:

```
<b>I want to eat <?php echo $keyword; ?></b>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i dont know i try your code but not work. I use eval function and it work fine on my code now.